# Is lazy initialization with immutable data always thread-safe?

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, immutability, lazy-initialization

I have two classes `A` and `B`:

```
class A {
    private final String someData;
    private B b;

    public String getSomeData() { return someData; }

    public B getB() {
        if (b == null) {
             b = new B(someData);
        }
        return b;
    }
}
```

where `B` is immutable and computes its data only from an instance of `A`. `A` has immutable semantics, but it's internals are mutable (like `hashCode` in `java.lang.String`).

When I call `getB()` from two different threads, and the calls overlap, I assume each thread gets its own instance of `B`. But since the constructor of `B` gets only immutable data, the two instances of `B` should be equal.

Is that correct? If not, must I make `getB()` synchronized to make it thread-safe?

Assume that B implements equals(), which compares all instance variables of B. Same for hashCode()

Comment: Does `B` override `equals`?

Comment: When two threads call `getB()` at the same time it could happen that each thread has its own object `B` or it could also happen that they both share the same `B`. Question here is like @MarkElliot points out: does `B` override `equals()` and `hashCode()`?

Comment: @MarkElliot yes, assume that `B` implements `equals()`, which compares all instance variables of `B`. Same for `hashCode()`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is *not* thread-safe, because you haven't created any "happens-before" relationships with `volatile` or `synchronized`, so it's possible for the two threads to interfere with each other.

The problem is that although `b = new B(someData)` means "allocate enough memory for an instance of `B`, then create the instance there, then point `b` to it", the system is allowed to implement it as "allocate enough memory for an instance of `B`, then point `b` to it, then create the instance" (since, in a single-threaded app, that's equivalent). So in your code, where two threads can create *separate* instances but return the *same* instance, there's a chance that one thread will return the other thread's instance *before the instance is fully initialized*.

Answer (score 0):

For "But since the constructor of B gets only immutable data, the two instances of B should be equal."
As you understand its not thread safe, one thread might get un-initialized B instance (B as null or inconsistent state where somedata not yet set) others might get b instance with somedata set.

To fix this you need synchronized getB method or use synchronized block with double-check lock or some non-blocking technique like AtomicReference. For you reference I am adding here sample code for how to achieve the correct threadSafe getB() method using AtomicReference.

```
class A {
    private final String someData = "somedata";
    private AtomicReference<B> bRef;

    public String getSomeData() { return someData; }

    public B getB() {
        if(bRef.get()== null){
            synchronized (this){
                if(bRef.get() == null)
                    bRef.compareAndSet(null,new B(someData));
            }
        }
        return bRef.get();
    }
}

class B{
    public B(String someData) {

    }
}
```

Comment: I'm hesitant to downvote this, because aside from its failure to initialize `b` (probably it should be named `bRef` to avoid confusion, and declared+initialized as `private final AtomicReference<B> bRef = new AtomicReference<B>()`), your code isn't *broken* . . . but it's really bizarre. Firstly, you shouldn't synchronize on `B.class`, because that means that all instances of `A` will require the same lock, which may also well be held by some other code (since `A` doesn't own `B.class`). Secondly, the `compareAndSet` is superfluous, since the reference is guaranteed to be `null` *[continued]*

Comment: *[continued]* at that location; you can just write `bRef.set(new B(someData))`, at which point you might as well just use a `volatile` field. The whole point of atomics is to avoid locking; if you ever find yourself combining atomics with `synchronized`, you can be pretty sure that you're doing something the wrong way.